# How to check when fgets returns an empty line?

Tags: c, file-io, char, fgets, enter

```
printf("Batch Mode\n");
FILE* batchFile;
char oneLine[LINE_MAX];
batchFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
bool done = false;

if(batchFile == NULL)
{
    perror("File");
    exit(1);
}   
while (fgets(oneLine,LIMIT,batchFile) != NULL && !done)
{
    processLine(oneLine, done);
}
```

So I have some concern regarding my code above. The problem is fgets still gets lines even if the lines just contain a newline character. So I need to eliminate this or at least be able to check for lines that contain only a newline.

I tried

```
if (strcpy(line, '\n') == 0)
{
    printf("an Enter key line\n");
    return;

}
```

But still it doesn't work.

Comment: The code with `strcpy()` should not have compiled.  If it did, you're either ignoring compiler warnings or not using enough of them.  If you have the `<string.h>` included, the code should be rejected by the compiler.

Comment: And also, nothing in this code changes `done` after it is initialized to `false`.